# What's the time derivative of this characteristic function?

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, characteristic-functions

I am taking a first course on continuous time methods for Finance and I am trying to solve the following problem:

[image]

I am able to solve it until item d). Let me show what I have so far.

We apply Ito's lemma on $r_t = X_t^2$ to get $dr_t = 2X_tdX_t + (dX_t)^2$. Define $\kappa = 2\hat{\kappa}$, $\sigma = 2\hat{\sigma}$ and $\theta = \frac{\hat{\sigma}}{2\hat{\kappa}}$. We can plug the dynamics for $X_t$ back in and derive that $dr_t = \kappa(\theta - r_t)dt + \sigma \sqrt{r_t}dZ_t$.

We are looking for the following object (where I am using $dt = \Delta$):

> $\phi(t, r_t; \omega) = E\left[e^{i\omega r_{t + dt}} | r_t \right]$

Let $\omega$ be fixed. I will omit it for now just for brevity. Using the Kolmogorov Backward Equation, the characteristic function must satisfy the following PDE:
$$ \phi_t(t, r_t)  + \phi_r(t, r_t) \cdot \kappa(\theta - r_t) + \frac{\sigma^2}{2}r_{t}\cdot \phi_{rr}(t, r_t) = 0, \quad \text{with} \quad \phi(t + dt, r_{t + dt}) = e^{i\omega r_{t+d_t}}$$

Now, we look for an exponentially affine solution. Under this guess, we have that:

$$ \phi_t = \phi \cdot (\dot{a}_0 (t) + \dot{a}_1 (t)r)\\
 \phi_r = \phi \cdot a_1 (t)\\
 \phi_{rr} = \phi \cdot (a_1 (t))^2$$

Plugging this back into the PDE, doing the algebra and noticing that this must be valid for any $r_t$ yields the following two ODEs:

$$\dot{a}_1(t) - \kappa a_1 (t) + \frac{\sigma^2}{2}(a_{1}(t))^2 = 0, \quad \text{with} \quad a_1(t+dt) = i\omega \\
 \dot{a}_0(t) + \kappa \theta a_1(t)  = 0, \quad \text{with}\quad a_0(t+dt) = 0$$

**Now what I can't understand:**

We are given the solution for $\phi$. Ideally, I'd like to take derivatives with respect to $r$ and with respect to $t$, plug it in back into the PDE and check that it indeed satisfies the equation. However, I don't see time $t$ in the characteristic function. I tried to do it assuming that $\phi_t = 0$ but that didn't work. I am clearly missing something. My two questions are:

1. *Why does time $t$ does not appear in the final solution?*
2. *What is the correct derivative with respect to time?*

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Your $\phi_t$ is missing a factor of $r$.

Comment: @BobTerrell That is true, thanks! But it was a mistake just for typing it here into the website, not on my own notes. The questions remain.